# Calling WCF Data Service custom method

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have made the following custom method

```
[WebGet]
public string GetAllCars()
{

    return "hello";

}
```

I am consuming this function from browser and it works fine
but when I am consuming through a web app by service reference Execute method
it runs fine but the result cant be seen through quick watch, queryoperationresponse is there but dont know how to get the string from the result

here is the code:

```
ServiceReference1.SampleDBEntities uricontext = new ServiceReference1.SampleDBEntities(new Uri("http://localhost/website2/wcfservice1.svc"));
    uricontext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var proxycontext = uricontext.Execute<String>(new Uri("http://localhost/website2/wcfdataservice1.svc/GetAllCars"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the result "Strings" we need to "foreach" the resultant variable like this:

```
 ServiceReference1.SampleDBEntities uricontext = new ServiceReference1.SampleDBEntities(new Uri("http://localhost/website2/wcfservice1.svc"));
        uricontext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        var proxycontext = uricontext.Execute<String>(new Uri("http://localhost/website2/wcfdataservice1.svc/GetAllCars"));
      //  var s = proxycontext.ToString();
        foreach (var r in proxycontext)
        {
            Response.Write(r.ToString());
        }
```

It worked! and the problem is solved now.

Comment: I prefer using `FirstOrDefault()`, Execute returns an `IEnumerable<string>` but with either zero or one item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

To get scalar values from a WCF Data Service proxy, it is best practice to call `FirstOrDefault()` on the result;

```
    private T ExecuteScalar<T>(Uri uri)
    {
        return Execute<T>(uri).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
public string GetAllCars()
{
    return ExecuteScalar<string>(
        "http://localhost/website2/wcfdataservice1.svc/GetAllCars");
}
```